# Working with openCV in the new Android Studio 3.4?

Tags: java, android, opencv

This is the first time I'm working on an android project which deals with OpenCv , and my goal here is to read the number plate of vehicle and fetch the details from a server . After reading a couple of articles ,i came to know that the articles seems to be outdated since I'm working with the new Android Studio 3.4 the process of Adding the Module dependency seems a bit different so if anyone has encounter this could you please guide me out of this problem .

This is the articles that i mention about :

https://android.jlelse.eu/a-beginners-guide-to-setting-up-opencv-android-library-on-android-studio-19794e220f3c

https://medium.com/easyread/integrating-your-android-app-with-opencv-library-266b2ea913d3

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's the same process as mentioned in the articles, I'm working on a project in Android studio 3.4 and Opencv 3.2

Comment: @Amine When the Add Module Dependency pop up it says "Nothing to show" even after i follow the steps described in the article . What do you think the problem would be ?

Comment: Please check again the steps maybe you are not pointing to the `app` module when adding dependencies.

Answer (score 21):

My solution for Android Studio 3.4 and OpenCV 4.1 was to import module from  opencv/sdk directory and not in opencv/sdk/java as described in most tutorials.

The IDE suggests ":sdk" as module name but you can change it.

Now it was possible to add opencv dependency in the project structure.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your time . But i have work my way around Mobile Vision API which has delivered what is needed to achieved .

Comment: Zillion kiss for you since yesterday I'm struggling with this, now it got resolved. thanks

Comment: Thank you!!!! Man, it has solved my problem. Very Stupid mistake in these tutorials, where they ask java, but sdk directory solves it!!!

Answer (score 14):

Same problem for me, the Add Module Dependency pop up says "Nothing to show", so I edited the files manually. In this  beginner's guide https://android.jlelse.eu/a-beginners-guide-to-setting-up-opencv-android-library-on-android-studio-19794e220f3c instead of step 5, edit these files as follow :

settings.gradle :

```
include ':app'
include ':opencv'
```

(where opencv is the name of the library you gave at step 3, screenshot 4)

In file gradle.properties (Module: opencv)

Replace line

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
```

By:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
```

Remove line:

```
applicationId "org.opencv"
```

In the end it, this file looks like this :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion "28.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 28

    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
}
```

In file build.gradle (Module: app)

Add the following line in the dependencies section :

```
implementation project(':opencv')
```

Then resume at step 6 of the beginner's guide.

Comment: Thanks for your answer . But i work my way around by using Mobile Vision API instead of OpenCV and MV API has delivered what is needed .

Comment: This worked perfectly for me in Android Studio 3.5. Thanks!