# Unable to figure out how to import opencv properly

Tags: android, opencv, intellij-idea

So I tried to follow the instruction given from online but none of them has a solution. My Main issue with intellij with import module from existing module. I assume, since import module button is gone, Module from Existing Source replaces import module now. Main issue is that I can't use opencv library after importing them. And I imported opencv-andorid sdk as website suggested. But it won't let me add any library on it. Also it is nothing like

https://android.jlelse.eu/a-beginners-guide-to-setting-up-opencv-android-library-on-android-studio-19794e220f3c

this website or

https://medium.com/@kashafahmed/a-proper-beginners-guide-to-installing-opencv-android-in-android-studio-updated-5fe7f3399e1c

on inteillij IDE.

I would like to have a step by step instruction if possible from new intellij IDE 2019.

Answer (score 0):

I have ask the same problem importing opencv at Android Studio 3.4 ,it might be quite similar with Intellij IDE 2019 with Android Stu. 3.4 ,[here is some answer from my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55835542/working-with-opencv-in-the-new-android-studio-3-4). But for me i switch to Mobile Vision API instead of OpenCv and have achieved what I wanted. Hope it Solves u your problem.

Comment: Apparently there is no import module button on Intellij... So i had to install Android Studio

Comment: Ok give it a shot . Hope it solved your problem. If your goal is to read Characters only than you can try Mobile Vision API it works well enough for what i required .