# Android app exit while loading external library

Tags: opencv, android

I'm trying to add `opencv4` to my android app, and did everything as in [this](https://medium.com/@linjunghsuan/add-opencv-library-into-android-studio-6b02bc2920c0) post.

I added `System.loadLibrary` to the begining of my kotlin file s below:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    companion object {
        init {
            System.loadLibrary("opencv_java4")
        }
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) { }
```

But the app exit after launching with the below:

```sh
09/22 16:08:04: Launching 'app' on Pixel 3a API 29.
$ adb shell am start -n "hasan.tts_mobile/hasan.tts_mobile.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Waiting for process to come online...
Timed out waiting for process to appear on Pixel_3a_API_29 [emulator-5554].
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55937338/2441637), it looks there is something changed in `opencv 4` so that all existing tutorials talking about importing `java` folder as module, while actually the one required to be imported is the `skd` folder itself.

You can use [JavaCV](https://github.com/bytedeco/javacv) that is a wrapper of OpenCV, or do OpenCV manually as below:

1- From [here](https://opencv.org/releases/) download `OpenCV – 4.1.1` for Android

2- Extract the folder, it will be extracted to `OpenCV-android-sdk`, that contains the following:

```sh
Hasans-Air:OpenCV-android-sdk hasan$ ls
LICENSE     README.android  samples     sdk
```

3- Head to your project at Android Studio

4- File -> New -> Import Module

5- Select the `sdk` folder in the extracted folder in point 2, as shown the proposed `module name` is `:sdk` but you can rename it like `:sdkOpenCV4`, do not forget the `:` in front of the name

[image]

6- Right click the `app`, select `Open Module Settings`, select Dependencies, then click the `app` module, in the `Declared Dependencies` tap click `+` then you'll see the `OpenCV` module there, click add it, click `Apply` then `Add`:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

7- From `OpenCV SDK` copy the `sdk/native/libs` folder, and go to tour application folder `src/main` and paste it inside it, then rename the `libs` folder to `jnilibs`, so that in your application `src/main` folder
you'll be having:

[image]

8- In the `OnCreate` you can add a check before start using it:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)


        val ocvLoaded = OpenCVLoader.initDebug()
        if (ocvLoaded) {
            Toast.makeText(
                this@MainActivity, "OpenCV loaded",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
            ).show()
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(
                this@MainActivity, "Unable to load OpenCV",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
            ).show()
            Log.d("openCV", "loader: ${OpenCVLoader.initDebug()}")
        }
    }
}
```